# returning the file location Emmet Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

I want to make it so that using the keyboard shortcut or the abbreviation + tab, the location of the current file is returned to Sublime Text, possibly using Emmet

I installed Emmet but did not figure out where custom functions can be used there